# Ion-current sensing in ignition coils

Tags: automotive, coil, sensing

Variety of IC engine manufacturers have eliminated acoustic knock sensors from recent designs. Those got replaced with [Ion current sensing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.833.6818&rep=rep1&type=pdf) circuitry (feedback from the spark-plug).

In parallel, [SMART Ignition Coils](http://bmwmotorcycletech.info/ionization-current-sensing-ignition-susbystem.pdf) (those directly mounted on a smart-plug) are becoming a commodity.

Such coils normally have 3 pins:

- +12V for the primary coil
- Ground
- +5V TTL for the control signal

The question I have is - how can Ion-current be sensed on the same control pin?

Comment: It can be switched? I may be wrong, but I kinda doubt that the ion is sensed in the same moment that the plug sparks. If I were to design a system like that, I think it would make more sense (sic) to sniff for ions in the milliseconds/microseconds before the ignition is supposed to take place, and then switch from the sensor circuit to the ignition circuit to initiate a spark, and then switch back.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. But how on earth did they do it? I would imagine there should be a feed-back pin interfacing the 2ndary coil. But there isn't.

Comment: Recently? Delphi did this for GM ending up in SAAB ecotech engines around the year 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ignition coil is a transformer. As such, it is perfectly capable of coupling signals in both directions. High-frequency noise in the secondary current becomes high-frequency noise on the primary, where it can be analyzed using an FFT as described in the first paper.

However, the Delphi paper clearly shows that the ion current detection **is** done on the secondary side.